# Get a subarray from a 3d matrix by fixing one axis like in NumPy index+slices

Tags: javascript, python, matrix

My input is a 3x3x3 array such as this one:

```
m = [[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]],
     [[9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17]],
     [[18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23], [24, 25, 26]]]
```

And these are the outputs that I would like to get, using only vectorial or matricial operations:

```
out1 = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]      (corresponding to indice 0 along first axis)
out2 = [[0,1,2],[9,10,11],[18,19,20]] (corresponding to indice 0 along second axis)
out3 = [[0,3,6],[9,12,15],[18,21,24]] (corresponding to indice 0 along third axis)
```

I know that I can do that with python using numpy like this:

```
cube = np.arange(27).resize(3,3,3)
out1 = cube[0,:,:]
out2 = cube[:,0,:]
out3 = cube[:,:,0]
```

But I need to implement this in javascript. I know how to to do it with loops and indices but I thought there may be a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Your input is not a matrix. It is a third-order tensor. And your output is a 3x3 matrix. Are you just looking for some mathematical notation? Then, this is off-topic here.

Comment: Sorry for the first post as it was not clear enought, I reformulate my problem, hoping it's more understandable!
**RoryDaulton** the question is how to translate the slicing function of python in matrix operation.
**NicoSchertler** how a third-order tensor is different of a third-order matrix?

Comment: If you need the functionality in another language, then please state that language. Matrices and vectors are special tensors with two dimensions or one dimension, respectively. Something that has three dimensions like your cube cannot be a matrix. There is no third-order matrix.

Comment: And by dimension I do not mean the number of entries in a row/column but the dimensionality of the array that is used to represent the tensor (how many indices you need to address an entry).

Comment: Yes, i understand what you say, I had no idea that you could not call that a matrix. So it's a third-order tensor.

Comment: Back to your question: You are better off doing this manually with some loops. Although there might be a tensor operation (I am not that familiar with their algebra), you would need a library that supports tensor operations. And the implementation is most likely much less efficient because it has to be more general.

Comment: I was figuring the same thing... Thanks for the help and have a nice day !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`numjs` package that strives to transplant NumPy onto JS](https://github.com/nicolaspanel/numjs) (specifically, [`ndarray.pick`](https://github.com/scijs/ndarray#arraypickp0-p1-) from the underlying [`scijs/ndarray` package](https://github.com/scijs/ndarray)):

```js
var m = nj.array([[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]],
     [[9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17]],
     [[18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23], [24, 25, 26]]]);

console.log(m.pick(0,null,null));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/nicolaspanel/numjs@0.15.1/dist/numjs.min.js"></script>
```

Prints:

```
"[[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]"
```